# Set the same cookies webrequest to web browser client in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I use webrequest in asp.net page (run on server) to get google drive direct download link. After that, I send this link to client ( they use browser ex: chrome, firefox) for download this file. But issuie is cookie, webrequest cookie and client cookie not the same same. Ofcourse they can't download.
So, how I can set webrequest cookie to client?
Or how make webrequest cookie and client cookie to the same same? Thank and hope some idea to solve this problem. This my code:

```
            HttpWebRequest objWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);            
            objWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            objWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse objWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = objWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(readStream);
            string link = ""; //=> this link i need to send client
            foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='uc-download-link']"))
            {                link += row.Attributes["href"].Value;            }
```

Comment: Cookies are an area always under the full control of the browser. So any way you can set them will have to be client side. However, maybe it is not nessesary? See, cookies are sometimes turned off. And to compensate for that, the Session ID is usually appended to every link. Of course if there is a valid cookie on the client side, it could be the link session ID is never looked at and likely set to what is in the cookie instantly. But it is worth a try at least.

Comment: So, may be use webrequest at client?  Maybe javascript can do that. Javascript function request url, receive html code, after that get link form html code, and we have link with a cookie or session.

Comment: First point would be to try what happens if you add teh Session ID to the URL. You know, before you go out of your way to do what is practically hacking the users computer.